# How can I rollback changesets of other context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I have two liquibase context - master and test.
In test context there are insert test data to db.
If I run tests, all changesets are using.
And if I run app, only master changesets are using.

But if I run app after tests, I can see all data in DB (master and test).
I want to automatically rollback test changesets, when I run app.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the liquibase [Rollback](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/rollback.html) command to undo changeSets of your test context before running the application.

A rollback or any other Liquibase command can be executed using the command line utility, Ant or Maven.

See an example using the [Rollback Maven Goal](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/maven_rollback.html):

```
mvn liquibase:rollback 
-Dliquibase.properties=./project.properties 
-Dliquibase.rollbackDate=2016-01-01 
-Dliquibase.contexts=test
```

In this case, I used the rollback date mode. It will rollback all changesets executed after January 1 2016 belonging to a context called test.